# Ebook usage, distribution, recommendations and trends

Tags: ebook-management, publishing, download

I work for a national cancer charity. We produce all our printed content as ebooks available from our website. But the download of ebook formats (pdf, Mobi and epub) is pretty low.

There are around 375,000 new cancer cases in the UK every year, about 1,000 every day (2016-2018). So we want our content to reach as many people as possible.

*We're looking for any report/summary on ebook usage, recommendations and trends*. But **if anyone can suggest the best places to publish/distribute our free ebooks to reach more people, we'd be very grateful**?

Comment: For ebooks publish them where people expect e/g/ Amazon, Kobo How many people read your website - make the ebook also readable as HTML -

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Our company website is quite busy. We’re the second largest charity and 1 in 2 people in the UK will get cancer in their lifetime, but very few of them download our publications from our website. I think you’re right. We need to put our resources on ebook repositories where people can see and download them free of charge.

Comment: Also note the make them available as HTML. Many people don't download they are online all the time and will read directly from the website.

Comment: Just curious: people with cancer use paper books intensively, and they only "avoid" ebooks? Or maybe they are busy with other stuff regarding their health and life and they really do not have *any* books high on their priority list? The solution for each case are significantly different.

Comment: Another question: "the download of ebook formats ... is pretty low" - which content is used "pretty high"? Paper? Web? Clay tablets? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can publish on Smashwords (aka Draft2Digital) and set the price to free, and it will propagate the price to many ebook distributors. You can also set Google Play's price to free.

For Amazon, you can sell something at 99 cents which is practically free as well.

But after the free ebooks are available elsewhere, you can do pricematch. Here's what you can do as of May 2022:

1. Start at Amazon KDP Dashboard
2. Click on the help button at the top right hand corner.
3. Scroll down to the contact us button on the bottom left corner.
4. Select the pricing option, then select price match and provide the
   requested information, including at least two addresses where your
   book can be purchased for zero dollars.

You should hear back from them in a couple of days and the book will
be price matched within a week. You have to do this for each of the
Amazon stores separately, so .com, .ca, .uk etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. This option is perfect.